# Is it possible to have environment and env_file in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I am new to Gitlab CI/CD and I have the following issue.

Suppose I have some environment variables in my local setup in an `.env` file. Something like this:

```
SOME_URL=https://someurl.com/
SECRET_KEY=verysecretkey
```

For my setup to work, I need both of these environment variables. The `SECRET_KEY` is not in the `.env` for the deployment. It is in the "secrets" in GitLab. If I have something like this in my Docker Compose file:

```
environment:
  SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
env_file:
  - .env
```

My two questions are:

1. In my local setup, will I have in my environment variables both `SECRET_KEY` and `SOME_URL`?
2. In GitLab, am I going to be able to replace `SECRET_KEY` with secrets?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables defined in Gitlab CI/CD are available inside the pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml). In the step, you are executing the docker-compose command, the variable will be replaced then set in your container thanks to environment: SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}. That should be fine.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/ 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution